# How do I efficiently load multiple has_many relationships in CodeIgniter DataMapper ORM?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-datamapper

Given the following models:

Category: has_many(‘template’)
Template: has_many(‘tag’, ‘procedure’)

What is the most efficient way to load ALL objects related to ALL categories?

For instance, I’m currently doing the following, but hopefully there is a better way:

```
// Load all Category objects
$categories = new Category();
$categories->get();

// Load all Template objects related to each Category
foreach($categories as $category)
{
  $category->templates->get();

  // Load all the Tag and Procedure objects related to each template
  foreach($category->templates as $template)
  {
    $template->tags->get();
    $template->procedures->get();
  }
}
```

Right now this code is executing over 200 queries on one particular page.

Comment: Does Datamapper have any type of eager loading ? ie: Model::get(array('include'=>array('tags', 'procedures'))). or include_related methods ?

Comment: Yes, in the form of include_related, but that doesn't work for has_many's, as Datamapper's hydration currently can't handle repetition in the query result.

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this? I am dealing with essentially the same situation. I'm loading about 600 models, and would like to include related models for each one, so I'm looping through the first list of models just like you are, and running a `get()` for each one. The number of queries being run seems to be effecting memory available on my machine. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: @WanWizard any change we'll see an update on this? Currently this is a huge drawback. And since we've chosen to use DataMapper in the past, it's not that easy to switch to another solution...

Comment: @WanWizard maybe an auto_populate_has_many_count option would do allready??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
foreach($categories as $category)
    {
        // here you can use the $category object
        foreach($category->templates as $template){
            // here you can use the $template object
            foreach($template->tags as $tags){
                // here you can use the $tags object
            }
            foreach($template->procedures as $proceadures){
                // here you can use the $proceadures object
            }
        }
    }
```

Make sure you have activated the autopopulate option in the datamapper config application/config/datamapper.php and you dont need to run get() on all models

```
$config['auto_populate_has_many'] = TRUE;
$config['auto_populate_has_one'] = TRUE;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: While auto-populating all has_many relationships will be "efficient" in that you won't have to write as many get()s, it could be incredibly inefficient in terms of resource usage. If there are lots of unnecessary child objects that get included with every parent query this could bog down the code.

Comment: Any news on this problem? Still using datamapper in our application and I would LOVE a way to reduce the amount of queries!!!