# DataMapper ORM - How to get all of a model and each instance's related data

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm, codeigniter-datamapper

I do not understand how to do the following:

Lets say I have a product table, and a photo table. 1 Product has many photos.  So in the product model I do:

```
var $has_many = array("category", "photo");
```

Now I want to get all products and relate each of their photos to them. How can I do this? Currently, in my controller I am going through each of the products and querying photos and passing a separate array that way. This CANNOT be ideal. I should be able to tie each photo to the specific product directly no?

Logically, this would work (but it doesnt?)

```
$product = new Product;
$products = $product->get_by_related_category('name', $where);
$photos = $product->photo->get();
```

See what I'm getting at? **I would love to just pass that $products variable to my view, be able to foreach through it, and have an array of photos tied to each product object.**

How can I accomplish this? Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With a "has many" relation you basically have two way to fetch the related information with SQL:

1. You can join the other table in like `select products.*, photos.* from products left outer join photos on products.id = photos.product_id`. This way you will have "duplicate" products data so you need to handle the results accordingly. Unfortunately [`include_related()`](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/getadvanced.html#include_related) doesn't support this directly, it would create the duplicated  products with each of them have one related photo in your case.
2. You can run two queries, first fetching the products (`select * from products where ...`) and then fetching the photos with the id's of the selected products (`select * from photos where product_id in (...)`) and sort out what photos row should go what product. There's no built-in functionality for this in DMZ, but here's what I've coded up for a model base class (that extends the `DataMapper` class) that can be used like this:

   ```
   $products = new Product;
   $products = $products
       ->get_by_related_category('name', $where) // first get the parent objects
       ->load_related('photo'); // then load in the related ones inside them
   foreach ($products as $product) {
       // unique product instances as before
       foreach ($product->photo as $photo) {
           // and every product has a list of related photos 
           // for each product individualy
       }
   }
   ```

   The method below will gather the id's of the parent objects, run one SQL query with the ids in a `where_in()` and sort the results out for the parent object's related field object (unfortunately its a little long and doesn't support many-to-many relations).

```
/**
 * load_related
 * 
 * Loads related has_many objects efficiently
 *
 * @param string $related_field_name the name of the relation
 * @param callable $filter_function callback to place extra conditions on the related model query
 */ 
public function load_related($related_field_name, $filter_function = null) {
    $related_properties = $this->_get_related_properties($related_field_name);
    $related_models = new $related_properties['class'];
    $join_field = $related_properties['join_self_as'].'_id';

    $ids = array_unique(array_filter(array_merge(array('id' => $this->id), array_column($this->all, 'id')), 'intval'));
    if (empty($ids)) {
        return $this;
    }

    $related_models->where_in($join_field, $ids);
    if (is_callable($filter_function)) {
        call_user_func($filter_function, $related_models);
    }

    $related_models = $related_models->get();
    $related_models = array_group_by($related_models, $join_field);

    foreach ($this->all as $i => $row) {
        $related_models_to_row = isset($related_models[$row->id]) ? $related_models[$row->id] : null;
        if ($related_models_to_row) {
            $this->all[$i]->{$related_field_name} = reset($related_models_to_row);
            $this->all[$i]->{$related_field_name}->all = $related_models_to_row;
        }
    }

    if (isset($related_models[$this->id])) {
        $this->{$related_field_name} = $related_models[$this->id];
    }

    return $this;
}

// The two array helper functions used above from my_array_helper.php
function array_group_by($arr, $key, $index_by_col = false) {
    $re = array();
    foreach ($arr as $v) {
        if (!isset($re[$v[$key]])) {
            $re[$v[$key]] = array();
        }
        if ($index_by_col === false) {
            $re[$v[$key]][] = $v;
        } else {
            $re[$v[$key]][$v[$index_by_col]] = $v;
        }
    }
    return $re;
}

function array_column($arr, $key, $assoc = false) {
    if (empty($arr)) {
        return array();
    }
    $tmp = array();
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        if ($assoc === true) {
            $tmp[$k] = $v[$key];
        } elseif (is_string($assoc)) {
            $tmp[$v[$assoc]] = $v[$key];
        } else {
            $tmp[] =  $v[$key];
        }
    }
    return $tmp;
}
```

Comment: I think I found a better solution, and it works for many to many relations as well.

Comment: @Brainfeeder, you made me curious, what have you found?

Comment: Check the answer I posted :) However, if you have a large amount of related objects your solution might be better anyway. The way I do it now loads them if you need them or not... But for which I needed the data it is OK.

Answer (score 0):

I'm kinda exploring DM for a while now and I needed the same functionality. At first the `load_related` function from the other answer seemed to be the solution for this.
I did some further research though. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16088476/1397220) answer to another question and it made me thinking if there wasn't a way to autopopulate only some of the relations.
Well, there is !!

You can set this 'option' if you make a relation in a model.

```
//Instead of doing this:
var $has_many = array('user_picture');

//Do this
var $has_many = array(
    'user_picture' => array(
        'auto_populate' => TRUE,
    ),
 );
```

Now the pictures will be available in a user object.

```
foreach ($u as $user) {

    foreach ($user->user_picture as $picture) {
        // Do your thing with the pictures
    }

}
```

I found it on [this page](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/advancedrelations.html) from the docs.

Enjoy!